# CLASSIC ASP: Replace all characters from email string - less @ and "."

Tags: email, replace, asp-classic

I'm trying to replace all characters from an Email String - less @ and "." with Classic ASP

Something like this:

```
JOHN.DOE@EMAIL.COM 
****.***@*****.***

CARL_SAGAN@EMAIL.COM
**********@*****.***
```

I Try with "REPLACE(EMAIL, J, *)" - but with this I need to replace each characters (and this includes special characters too, like "_" "-"  and others..)

There is any other alternative?

tks!

==
UPDATE:

I'm got a better solution with REGEX:

```
Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "[A-Za-z]"
regEx.Global = True
tipEmail = regEx.Replace(Email, "*")
```

But I'm not so expert. This RegEX Pattern excludes AZ/az and I need to exclude ALL characters - less @ and "."

tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

the solution -

```
Dim regEx
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "[^@.]"
regEx.Global = True
tipEmail = regEx.Replace(Email, "*")
```